# Asp.net database content cache

Tags: asp.net, caching, ckeditor

I am having an ASP.NET website, where most of the content for home page contents coming from database which can be managed by the Admin using the CKEditor.

My problem is, every time user refresh or open the home page it loads from the database. Is there any good method to cache these contents for certain time or till Admin change the contents.
What is the best approach for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache the the data instead of hitting the database or you can use ASP.NET caching and cache by page, control...etc, there are a lot of options, take a look at the articles below:

[.NET Data Caching](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043655/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100902-1.aspx)

[Caching with ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113508/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022802-1.aspx)